# Get items from a Sharepoint list to Excel using Power Query that uses folders

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerquery

I do have a Sharepoint list where the elements are group in folders. When I try to connect from Excel to the list using Power Query, I do get the list, but only the names of the folders. I would like the items in the folders and not just the folders - Any suggestions?

Current query (in Danish):
let Kilde = SharePoint.Tables("XXXX", [Implementation = "2.0", ViewMode = "Default"]), #"Navigation 1" =

Kilde{[Id = "XXX"]}[Items]
in #"Navigation 1"

Comment: Try the SharePoint.Files or Sharpoint.Contents() connectors instead of Sharepoint.Tables()